# share functions between two files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a quiz program in which I have a front end file where the user inputs answers and a back end question storing file. I want to share functions which have been defined in each of these files between both the files however I can only seem to share functions from one file to the other and not from both files with each other

i have tried in file1 doing: from file2 import function2 and then in file2 doing: from file1 import function1. However this doesnt work. I just get a cannot import function1 error.

```
#file1 (backend)
from physicstester_frontend import answer

def quantum_test():

    while True:
        qq1 = "describe the experiments that lead to wave particle duality."
        print(qq1)
        answer()
        qq1_words = ["double slit", "diffraction", "interference", "wave", "photoelectric", "effect", "photon"]
        if all(word in ans for word in qq1_words):
            print("correct") #prints correct if all required words are in string
            break  
        else:
            print("not a full description, try again")
            continue

#file2 (frontend)
from physicstester_data import quantum_test

print("physics tester")
print("topics: \nQuantum\n..\n..\n..")
topics = input("which topic would you like to be tested on?: ")

if topics.lower() == "quantum":
    quantum_test()

def answer():
    global ans
    ans = input("answer: ")
```

when i do this i get

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'quantum_test' from 'physicstester_data'
```

Comment: please share directory structure and file1 and file2 filenames

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Comment: Could you just create a third file, in which you put all the functions that are shared across the server file and the client file?

Comment: The filenames are `physicstester_data.py` and `physicstester_frontend.py`?

Comment: yes those are the file names

Comment: creating a third file could work but the answer() function which takes user input need to be on the front end file

Comment: If the files are in the same folder/directory this should work. Searching for `ImportError` should give you a plethora of things to consider - you may even find a duplicate.  Without knowing *where* these files are we won't be able to help.  Ypu also haven't shown how you are using those two files - you should create a [mcve] that we can use to diagnose the problem.

Comment: what if you put the answer() function definition right on top of file2, before the import?

Answer (score 0):

`import` cycles are Bad.

Put `def answer()` in its own file, `answer.py`, to break the cycle.